# After JQuery .load() my buttons don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, load

I've been working on a Website where i want to load an html file to a div with jquery. Everything works fine except my buttons in the loaded html. If i click on them nothing happens. And i cannot even add #btn:hover{cursor: pointer;} with css although every other styling works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main-content').load('./content/frontpage.html', complete);
});

function complete(){
  const Btn = document.getElementById('btn')
  
  //logs out the button nicely
  console.log(Btn);
  
  //Tried this way -- not working
  Btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("clicked");

  });

  //Tried this way as well -- not working
  $(document).on('click', '#btn', () => {
        console.log("clicked");
  })
}
```

```html
//index.html
...
<main id="main-content">

</main>
...

//frontpage.html
<section class="container">
  <button id="btn">Click me</button>
  
</section>
```

Anyone knows what is the problem? I searched for solutions but nothing works so far.

**EDIT:**

Oh and by the way, if i click the button from the console with:
document.getElementById('btn').click();

it works... Anyone knows anything what the hell is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not closing line 3 as:

```
});
```

Another way to add a click listener is also:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    console.log("clicked");
})
```

Comment: yea sorry it was my mistake, i copied the line wrong. But it doesnt work with your solution either. :(

Comment: Do you mean correcting line 3 to }); doesn't fix the issue, or that my other suggestion doesn't work?

Comment: neither of them work for me. But the funny part is that if i click the button from the browser console it works. but on the ui it doesnt. z-index is pretty high so i have no clue what is going on

Answer (score 0):

Well.. Your code works well, except a syntax error below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main-content').load('frontpage.html', complete);
});

function complete() {
    ...
```

Comment: it was my mistake. I copied the line wrong. But it doesnt work